# Why is the CodeRush Xpress for Visual Studio 2012 question considered "Not a real question"?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, reopen-closed

The following question was closed as "not a real question": [CodeRush Xpress for Visual Studio 2012](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/12760990/2).

Can someone please explain why? I think the question is extremely clear. It has a single, solid, objective answer.

Not only is the close reason untrue, like with many closed StackExchange questions I've seen, but **the only answer that is present is misleading**. I would have posted the correct answer, but I can't because it's been closed. The view count indicates that it could have mislead over *4000* visitors from Google. I think no information is better than wrong information, and StackOverflow is pushing wrong information out to the general public because of this.

---

Since posting, this question has [been edited](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12760990/is-coderush-xpress-compatible-with-visual-studio-2012) and reopened.

Comment: The question isn't about programming. SO isn't a news site to get news about availability of softwares.

Comment: @LoïcFaure-Lacroix - some questions about programming tools are also on-topic.

Comment: I changed the close reason to one that's a little more specific.

Comment: @BilltheLizard, thanks. That seems more applicable, but it still isn't accurate. The question isn't asking for a recommendation; it's asking a question about development software compatibility.

Comment: @LoïcFaure-Lacroix, programming software compatibility is about programming to me. You can barely program without software. The question wasn't really even about news; I believe CodeRush Xpress worked perfectly in Visual Studio 2012 at the time the question was asked. That's not about getting news updates.

Comment: I don't think the answer is completely untrue. It's not available in the sense that it's not explicitly supported. It may work, but when stuff breaks, you're on your own.

Comment: @Stijn, thanks; I think you're right.

Answer (score 4):

The [original question](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/12760990/2) was closed because only the owners of CodeRush could possibly answer that question definitively, thus "cannot be reasonably answered". (Notice that your answer came from a [self-identified DevExpress employee](https://stackoverflow.com/users/312771/alex-skorkin).)

The close reasons don't always fit quite perfectly, but questions like these tend to get closed using one reason or another.

Comment: But don't most questions' answers need to come back to some definitive source? For example, a question about a syntax error in a programming language can only be "definitively answered" by referencing the language specification. What's the difference between referencing a language specification and a website, forum, or developer staff member? I could have answered the question correctly myself if it wasn't locked, and I'm not a CodeRush owner.

Comment: @Sam in coding questions, "definitive source" is typically in compilation and execution of the code. One is their own authority in that, there's no need to reach out for _owner-shmowner_ to find out right and wrong

Comment: @gnat, so what's the difference between that and this question? I didn't need to look for a "definitive source" to determine that the software was compatible with Visual Studio 2012. I just had to try installing and using it to find out.

Comment: @Sam - The original question was "*Is CodeRush Xpress **going to be made available** for Visual Studio 2012?*". That's not something that can be answered by installing and running the tools or even looking at the website. It's a completely arbitrary decision made by one or two people within the organization that owns the product. A programming question, on the otherhand, can be answered by anyone with a computer and a compiler. (In fact, in the case of bugs, etc., the compiler is an even more definitive source than the owners.)

Comment: The difference is similar to "Will Ford ever switch completely to electric vehicles?" vs "How do I replace a spark plug in my Fiesta?"

Comment: @JDB, it looks like we're interpreting the question differently. To me, "made available" basically means "made compatible with", which I think was already the case at the time of the question. I think most people who come to that question will be more interested in whether the product works with Visual Studio 2012 rather than whether the developer of the product will announce official support. Anyway, thanks for the explanation; I suppose the people who closed the question interpreted it the same way you did.